# How to create Kiosk mode application using Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, kiosk-mode

I'm trying to create an application using `Xamarin.iOS` to works as kiosk mode as done in the following link [Github](https://github.com/Cheesebaron/KioskModeSample)

Need your help on how to create a lock app in iOS with a given pin.

Comment: You can't enforce kiosk mode from an app. You can either use guided access from accessibility settings or enforce single app mode via supervision through Apple Configurator or an MDM solution.

Comment: Currently, we are developing own lock app to detect the user of the device with a unique pin allocated for the user to authenticate. Through which we can register the user name in database using an API call. Can we achieve it in iOS? @Paulw11

Comment: Do you want them to enter a PIN to access functions within your app or to lock the device itself?  You can do the first but not the second.